# Thread does not work correctly in chat application using c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety, fltk

I'm making a chat application client part using boost library and fltk for GUI. I make class for the client part and using thread to handle GUI from freezing 
the thread for the read part contain an infinite loop that waits to read from the server so i used the thread for this function in the client class 
the code i use

this is the thread in the constructor of client.cpp

```
#include "Client.h"


Client::Client(string ip, int port) :
    socket(ios),
    ep(asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"),5002)
{
    this->ip = "127.0.0.1";
    this->port = 5002;
    socket.connect(ep);
    thread t(&Client::run,this); // here the thread
    t.detach(); // i use detach to make it run alone so my app not wait it 
}
```

and this the run function which have the infinite loop waiting for to read from the server and added to the thread to not freez the GUI

```
void Client::run()
{
    while (true) {
        asio::streambuf buf;
        int read = asio::read_until(socket, buf, '\n');
        string message;
        istream in(&buf);
        getline(in, message);
        message.append("\n");
        buffer->append(message.c_str());
    }
}
```

**the problem is** that when I send a message it didn't come at the same time. it comes after some seconds may I sent 4 or 5 message they received together not as java when I make run function and the class extends thread I use an infinite loop in it the message comes at the same time and fast so what should I do to solve this problem, please I need help because I'm beginners in threads 
Thanks in advance

Comment: IMHO this ought to go to [Code Review SO](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) first. There are so many issues (including several synchronization issues) evident even in this little snippet. | OP, please write legibly -- in your case, capitalize your sentences properly, this is a PITA to read.

Comment: @DanMašek nope. This question is off-topic on Code Review, because the code doesn't work as intended. For more information, please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow Users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Comment out the GUI bits and replace them with cout.  It might be easier to debug your program then.  I'm not very familiar with Apple stuff.  How does the buffering work - does it transmit whenever you do a send or does it only transmit when the buffer is full?